# How strict is AirAsia with 7 kg carry-on limit?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage, low-cost-carriers, airasia

https://www.airasia.com/ot/en/baggage-info/cabin-baggage.page

> The total permitted weight for two (2) pieces must not exceed 7 kg.

My carry-on bag on the way here had plenty of print materials and was more than 20 kg, more than the hold luggage :)

*(One optimised for weight, and one optimised for size)*

Now the paperwork is gone, but some of the weight remains. Do they weigh bags?

---

Once in Puerto Rico I saw people being weighted on a scale before boarding a plane.

I'm not talking about bags, I'm talking about people!

---

Another example.

China is generally strict.

https://www.xiamenair.com/en-cn/PassengerService/passenger4_2.html

> The weight of each carried item must not exceed 5 kg (11 lbs.), and the volume must not exceed 20×40×55 cm.

I was lucky enough that some of my friends were travelling by train - I asked them to take some stuff for me while I followed regulation religiously.

I saw so many other people with way larger (and supposedly much heavier) luggage. But I did not notice any weighing device.

Comment: I don’t know about AirAsia in particular, but the more budget-airliney it is the stricter they are. Is your ticket super cheap? Do they sell “upgrade packages” for more baggage allowance? Then yes, they’ll probably check and nickel and dime you.

Comment: Conversely, I was on Norwegian for the first time recently (a terrific airline) and my carry bag was way, way, way over the strict limit.  (like 2x+ !) All the frequent travelers in the queue said that based on their previous frequent experience on that airline, it would be weighed and I'd have to pay the excess.  I was resigned to paying. However, the agent didn't even weigh it and it wasn't even mentioned at all!  (And the flight was full.)  I fear it is quite random you know?

Comment: @Fattie I flew Norwegian round trip between NY and London a few summers ago.  They did not weigh cabin bags in NY, but they did weigh them in London.  My bag was a couple of kilos  overweight, but I asked to repack it, whereupon I started removing the warm clothes I had brought to wear on the plane and putting them on.  They told me to proceed and did not reweigh my bag.

Comment: A good example.   Yes, it's quite random, unfortunately that's the way it is. To the OP's question, I have no experience of Air Asia

Comment: `but they did weigh them in London` - WOW... That is extreme! It would be so much nicer for us to just pass a single checkpoint at the gate and then forget, rather than be liable at the destination. Can I un-know that?

Answer (score 17):

I’ve flown with Air Asia a few times and with other airlines that have hand luggage weight limits.

I’ve never had my bag weighed by Air Asia, though I have seen others go through this. It does sometimes happen.

My impression is that I’d say it really depends on two factors.

1: How full the plane is. If they are expecting a packed flight then they will be very actively looking for luggage to force into the hold.

2: How big and heavy your bag looks. If you have a small handbag containing a 30kg weight and are strong enough to carry it as if it is nothing than you are much less likely to be caught out than somebody with a huge rucksack that they're struggling to carry but is just narrowly over the weight limit.

The general I’d advice I’d say is to prepare for the worst and keep your bag around the weight limit. However if it is unavoidable that your bag is heavy then try and hide this fact and make it appear as light as you can; also do your best to stay out of the way of the staff members who are weighing bags!

I'd say this is a case of weighing bags is something they reserve the right to do if they feel like it (e.g. if the plane is full) but isn't their standard practice.

Comment: Good advice. I've been doing it my all life - appearing small, appearing lightweight...